# How do I send a signal to a `Child` subprocess?

Tags: rust, signals

[`Child::kill`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.kill) sends a `SIGKILL`, but how can I send any other signal such as `SIGTERM`? I can probably use `libc` and its signal API, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does Windows even have the concept of "signal"? If not, there's probably nothing in the standard library.

Comment: Oh, windows... :(

Comment: Windows has [signal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx).

Comment: Does this mean that there is a valid reason to have this functionality in std?

Comment: Windows only appears to support a very limited subset of the POSIX and SUS signal sets. But at least TERM might be useful to allow a child shut down more gracefully before trying to kill it. But you can just grab the pid and use `libc` instead with some OS-specific code paths.

Comment: On Windows, the closest native equivalent to `SIGTERM` is [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890(v=vs.85).aspx) + [`WM_ENDSESSION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889(v=vs.85).aspx) for GUI applications and [`GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent) for console applications.

Comment: @jamieguinan There is no `kill` though, which is how you actually send a signal. The C run-time library emulates signals by converting some native OS events to signals. An application can only get a `SIGTERM` signal by calling [`raise`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwwzkt4c.aspx) to send it to itself. However, `SIGINT` and `SIGBREAK` can be generated from console control events.

Answer (score 36):

The [`nix`](https://docs.rs/nix) library does a good job of providing idiomatic rust wrappers around low-level UNIX operations, including sending and handling signals. In this case, you would create a [`nix::Pid`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.15.0/nix/unistd/struct.Pid.html) from `child_process.id()`, then pass it to [`kill`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.15.0/nix/sys/signal/fn.kill.html) like so:

```rust
use nix::unistd::Pid;
use nix::sys::signal::{self, Signal};

// Spawn child process.
let mut child = std::process::Command::new();
/* build rest of command */
child.spawn().unwrap();

// Send SIGTERM to child process.
signal::kill(Pid::from_raw(child.id()), Signal::SIGTERM).unwrap();
```

Comment: For those looking to do with just libc:


`pub fn kill_gracefully(child: &Child) {
    unsafe {
        libc::kill(child.id() as i32, libc::SIGTERM);
    }
}`

Answer (score 6):

## Use `kill`

The `kill` command has a bunch of options to send different signals to a process.
You can get the `child`'s process id using `.id()`.

It would be something like

```rust
let kill = Command::new("kill")
    // TODO: replace `TERM` to signal you want.
    .args(["-s", "TERM", &child.id().to_string()])
    .spawn()?;
kill.wait()?;
```

Comment: I really like this simple solution. Comparing it to the other upvoted answer and given [kill](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/kill/) is POSIX compliant I see no need to bring entire crate in for executing such a simple task.

Comment: this is using the executable command `/usr/bin/kill` that might be there as it might not. Also it spawn a new process to send signal to existing process, it is not as immediate as libc solution