# How to kill a running child process on Windows in Rust?

Tags: process, rust

I have a function which creates a process on Windows.

```
pub fn create_process(url: String) {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let _child = process::Command::new("cmd.exe")
            .arg("/C")
            .arg("ping")
            .arg(&url)
            .arg("-t")
            .spawn()
            .expect("Couldn't run 'ping'");
    });
}
```

I have a function which I want to terminate (kill) the process created by 'create_process()':

```
pub fn stop() {
    // ?????
}
```

How can I access the `_child` created in `create_process` function to terminate its process? Are there any other ways to kill that process?

Comment: Very relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49210815/1233251

Comment: Leading underscores indicate that a variable is unused, but you wish to use `_child`. Use `child` instead, please.

Comment: Didn't know it, thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR: Use the [kill](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.kill) method. For example:

```
use std::{process, thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    let mut child = process::Command::new("ping")
        .arg("8.8.8.8")
        .arg("-t")
        .spawn()
        .expect("Couldn't run 'ping'");

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
    child.kill().expect("!kill");
}
```

Notice how you don't need a separate thread, since the spawned process is already parallel to the parent process.

In your question, there is a code example which uses "cmd /C" to run the "ping". This spawns not one but two processes: the "cmd" process and the "ping" process. Killing the `child` will kill the "cmd" process but might leave the "ping" process running.

Using "cmd /C" is also dangerous, allowing for [command injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection).

> How can I access the `_child` created in the `create_process` function to terminate its process?

The `_child` [is `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#synthetic-implementations), which means that you can send it from thread to thread. The particulars of sending data across threads is likely to have been covered already in a number of corresponding Stack Overflow questions.

> Are there any other ways to kill that process?

You can use the native platform APIs. For example:

```
[dependencies]
gstuff = "0.5.2"
winapi = {version = "0.3.6", features = ["psapi", "shellapi"]}
```

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate gstuff;

use std::process;
use std::ptr::null_mut;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::DWORD;
use winapi::shared::ntdef::HANDLE;
use winapi::um::processthreadsapi::{OpenProcess, TerminateProcess};
use winapi::um::winnt::{PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, PROCESS_TERMINATE};

struct Process(HANDLE);
impl Process {
    fn open(pid: DWORD) -> Result<Process, String> {
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
        let pc = unsafe { OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0, pid) };
        if pc == null_mut() {
            return ERR!("!OpenProcess");
        }
        Ok(Process(pc))
    }

    fn kill(self) -> Result<(), String> {
        unsafe { TerminateProcess(self.0, 1) };
        Ok(())
    }
}
impl Drop for Process {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { winapi::um::handleapi::CloseHandle(self.0) };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let child = process::Command::new("ping")
        .arg("8.8.8.8")
        .arg("-t")
        .spawn()
        .expect("Couldn't run 'ping'");

    let pid = child.id();
    let pc = Process::open(pid as DWORD).expect("!open");
    println!("Process {} opened.", pid);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
    pc.kill().expect("!kill");
    println!("Process {} killed.", pid);
}
```