# How can I make a child process's stdin inherited and piped?

Tags: rust, process, stdin, child-process, sigint

I want to create a child process that will take normal input from the parent stdin. but at the same time i want to send signals through its stdin (ctrl+c - `0x03` like xterm does).
Using the standard `Command` api it is only possible to inherit or pipe, not both of them.

I tried to terminate the process, but it wasn't the desired behavior, I wanted the child process to get a `SIGINT` signal and decide what to do with it.
I also tried to spawn a thread to capture stdin input and then send the data through a channel and then write it to the piped stdin but it started to capture a line in the console and I don't want it.

I tried all of it on windows but I would like a cross platform solution for this.

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: `^C` isn't send to the process' stdin, but rather to the shell, which in turn sends `SIGINT` to the running process. You could add a signal handler to the parent process that when it receives `SIGINT` it sends `SIGINT` to the child, and then in child's signal handler decide what you want to do.

Comment: to emulate the SIGINT on windows you can send 0x03 to the child's stdin like how other terminal emulators do it. but my problem is how to send data to stdin while its inherited from the parent process

Answer (score 0):

> ctrl+c - 0x03 like xterm does [...] I would like a cross platform solution for this.

On unices at least that's definitely not sent through stdin, it's interpreted by the shell and translated to a signal (`SIGINT` on unices, ConsoleCtrlEvent on windows). Although I guess you could always make your program react to ETX by terminating. However note that ETX in a stream does not actually imply program termnation.

Rust's stdlib has extremely limited signal support exposed, [basically just SIGKILL](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.kill). You probably need to use low level platform-specific crates for something more complex, see various links and comments at [How do I send a signal to a `Child` subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210815/how-do-i-send-a-signal-to-a-child-subprocess)

That aside, if you want to mux over stdin you probably need to create a pipe manually (again I don't think there's a standard library API for that), [create the `Stdio` from the output side](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#impl-From%3COwnedFd%3E-for-Stdio), and `dup()` the input so you can pass one to the data source, and keep the other around to write to it.